# How do I export an SQL Server database to move it to a different server?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, ssis, export

I tried to export a database using the wizard in *SQL Server Management Studio*. It exported all the tables but with no primary keys or identity keys.

I realized I need to save SSIS Package. How do I exactly export a database using SSIS? I am actually on the `Save and Run Package` but I don't know if I should choose *SQL Server* or *File system*.

Is there a nice tutorial on exporting SQL Server database with identity keys and all?

What's happening is, I cannot insert new records on some table that just got exported. I found that *`Enable identity insert`* has something to do with it but I am not sure if I should enable them all while exporting.

Comment: What do you wish to export? The structure? The data? Both?

Comment: Your primary keys were exported if you exported the table. Would it be correct to restate your question as "I'd like to generate a script that has all my tables and the data too?"

Comment: both flup... I am actually moving the entire db to another server

Comment: :)... thank you billinkc... I am new to this... so you are probably right

Comment: @Siva: as long as the server versions are identical (or the target server has a newer version) - then yes.

Comment: @Siva I tried to backup and then restore... it says "the backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing "mydatabase" database... I made a backup on my old server and pasted the backup file on the new server... what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using *Restore Database* dialog user interface available on *SQL Server Management Studio*.

On the *`Restore Database`* dialog, click *`Options`* page and then check **`Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)`**. Click `OK` to restore the database.

### CAUTION:

Selecting *`WITH REPLACE`* option will overwrite the database files on the destination server that are using the same name as the database file names in the backup.  Read more about `WITH REPLACE` option on MSDN **[Restore Database (Options Page)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188223.aspx)** before selecting this option.

[image: WITH_REPLACE]